# jQuery .addClass() not working with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my code, I did

```
element.attr('class', element.attr('class') + ' state-active');
```

and the class `.state-active` got added to the element.

But when I try

```
element.addClass('state-active');
```

nothing happens.

It doesn't work, doesn't matter if I get the element with any of those:

```
var element = $('.state');
var element = angular.element($('.state'));
var element = angular.element($('.state')[0]);
```

I tried everything I could imagine, but none was enough. I noticed that `.css()` doesn't work either.

What could cause this issue and how do I solve this? For now my code is working, but that solution is not elegant...

Comment: Please try and reproduce it in a jsfiddle or plunker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using jQuery, try to approach the problem from a different angle (no pun intended!) such as using [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass). This allows you to set classes according to conditions using data binding. It's usually better that way, letting Angular do the nuts&bolts of actually changing the DOM.

Comment: Indeed, that sounds better. I'll change the code to do that!